# np.random.permutation with seed?

Tags: python, numpy, random, permutation

I want to use a seed with `np.random.permutation`, like

```
np.random.permutation(10, seed=42)
```

I get the following error:

```
"permutation() takes no keyword arguments"
```

How can I do that else? Thanks.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If you want it in one line, you can create a new `RandomState`, and call the `permutation` on that:

```
np.random.RandomState(seed=42).permutation(10)
```

This is better than just setting the seed of `np.random`, as it will have only a localized effect.

**NumPy 1.16 Update:**

`RandomState` is now considered a legacy feature. I see no indication that it will be deprecated any time soon, but now the recommended way to generate reproducible random numbers is via [Random Generators](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html), of which the default can be instantiated like so:

```
np.random.default_rng(seed=42).permutation(10)
```

Note that it appears like there's no guarantees of bitstream equivalence across different versions of NumPy for this generator, wheras for the `RandomState` the documentation states that ["This generator is considered frozen and will have no further improvements. It is guaranteed to produce the same values as the final point release of NumPy v1.16."](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/legacy.html)

Answer (score 34):

```
np.random.seed(42)
np.random.permutation(10)
```

If you want to call `np.random.permutation(10)` multiple times and get identical results, you also need to call `np.random.seed(42)` every time you call `permutation()`.

---

For instance,

```
np.random.seed(42)
print(np.random.permutation(10))
print(np.random.permutation(10))
```

will produce different results:

```
[8 1 5 0 7 2 9 4 3 6]
[0 1 8 5 3 4 7 9 6 2]
```

while

```
np.random.seed(42)
print(np.random.permutation(10))
np.random.seed(42)
print(np.random.permutation(10))
```

will give the same output:

```
[8 1 5 0 7 2 9 4 3 6]
[8 1 5 0 7 2 9 4 3 6]
```

Answer (score 4):

Set the seed in the previous line

```
np.random.seed(42)
np.random.permutation(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can break it down into:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(10)
np.random.permutation(10)
```

By initializing the random seed first, this will guarantee that you get the same permutation.

Comment: This answer is incomplete. Refer to the answer by Giorgos for more details.

Comment: It seems like we have to reset random seed every time to make sure we get the same random number