# How do I randomize a pandas column in the same order every time I run the code in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, random

This is my code:

```
random_idx = np.random.permutation(len(cIds))
train_Ids = cIds[random_idx[:train_size]]
```

Now, I want the list to be randomized in the same order every time I run this line of code.

Note: I do not want to save `random_idx` variable in a text file, and fetch the same list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [random.seed(): What does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639587/random-seed-what-does-it-do) and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639587/random-seed-what-does-it-do#comment74255398_22639752) is particularly useful.

Comment: You need to use a `seed` as is demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47742622/np-random-permutation-with-seed).

Comment: What is the range of seed value? like 0-100? -100 to 100? infinite ot infinite? Can it be negative? Fraction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`seed`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html?highlight=random) in order to tell numpy to generate the same random numbers:

```
np.random.seed(seed=1234)
random_idx = np.random.permutation(len(cIds))
```

same as:

```
np.random.seed(1234)
random_idx = np.random.permutation(len(cIds))
```

Or

```
random_idx = np.random.RandomState(seed=1234).permutation(len(cIds)
```

> seed: Must be convertible to 32 bit unsigned integers`

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do in in pandas style:

```
cIds.sample(n=train_size, 
            replace=False, 
            random_state=your_favorite_number_here)
```