# A fixed, random permutation with a seed

Tags: python, string, random, permutation

I want to take a column, C1, of strings in a dataframe, or you could just imagine a list of strings, and I want to get a new column where the entries, by row, are random permutations of the elements in the rows in C1.  Specifically, I want a fixed permutation of each element that is defined by a seed.  It would work like a function, f, where the following is true:

f(a) = b

and if I run it again

f(a) = b

where b is a random permutation of a.  I want f to be parameterized by some seed, so that it is easy for me to create a new function, g, that is also a random permutation satisfying

g(a) = c not equal to b

and when I run it again

g(a) = c not equal to b

Essentially, I want a list of random permutation functions, each of which is parameterized by something (say an integer) and is repeatable, given the fixed seed.  Or, in other words, I want a way to create new fix, random permutation functions by supplying a seed.

To show you what I mean, I did a quick search and found this site:

https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-random-shuffle/

Which leads to this code:

```
sr = ''.join(random.sample(s, len(s)))
```

This is a random permutation, but it is not repeatable.  That means that when you call it again

```
sr = ''.join(random.sample(s, len(s)))
```

sr is not the same, meaning that you don't "have" a FIXED, random permutation function.  So, a few minutes of searching does not produce anything.  I believe that there is a canonical way to get these random permutation functions and I need someone to show that canonical way.

Edit:
It looks like I did not use the seed properly (or at all).  If you call random sample the following way, you get a repeatable random permutation function:

```
>>> random.seed(53434)
>>> print(''.join(random.sample(a,len(a))))
```

Comment: What is your question about this?

Comment: Use Fisher-Yates algorithm with a seeded random-generator.

Comment: It might be enough to call `random.seed(your_seed)`, assuming the permutation code is using `random.random()`?

Comment: @joanis This is correct

Comment: Does this answer your question? [np.random.permutation with seed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47742622/np-random-permutation-with-seed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to call `random.seed()` when you want to reset your random sampling to the predicable state:

```
>>> random.seed(10)
>>> "".join(random.sample("asdfqwerzxcv", 12))
'xaercsfwdqzv'
>>> "".join(random.sample("asdfqwerzxcv", 12))
'zrwsfxdacqve'
>>> random.seed(10)
>>> "".join(random.sample("asdfqwerzxcv", 12))
'xaercsfwdqzv'
>>> "".join(random.sample("asdfqwerzxcv", 12))
'zrwsfxdacqve'
```